# Drawing circles on the form using e.graphics.drawellips?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to draw circles within circles and i have tried this but having difficulties

here is my code

```
Private Sub DrawCircle()
Dim g As Graphics
g = Panel1.CreateGraphics
Dim yellowPen As New Pen(Color.Yellow, 20)
Dim bluePen As New Pen(Color.Blue, 30)
Dim greenPen As New Pen(Color.Green, 20)
Dim skybluePen As New Pen(Color.AliceBlue, 20)
Dim voiletPen As New Pen(Color.Violet, 15)
Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)

' Draw ellipses
g.DrawEllipse(yellowPen, 260, 180, 10, 10)

g.DrawEllipse(greenPen, 240, 160, 50, 50)

g.DrawEllipse(bluePen, 220, 140, 90, 90)

g.DrawEllipse(greenPen, 200, 120, 130, 130)

g.DrawEllipse(skybluePen, 180, 100, 170, 170)

g.DrawEllipse(blackPen, 180, 100, 170, 170)

g.DrawEllipse(voiletPen, 170, 90, 190, 190)


End Sub

 Private Sub Panel1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
DrawCircle()
End Sub
```

It is working well but if there is any other option because if you change a little in this code everything goes wrong please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be i did't get your point right and  i think you are looking for an alternate solution 
here is one

```
Private colorForAllCircles As Color
Private ReadOnly rand As New Random

Function RandomColor() As Color
Return Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256))
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
Dim centerX, centerY As Integer
Dim cornerX, cornerY As Integer
Dim radius As Integer
Dim greenPen As New Pen(Brushes.Blue)

centerX = 300
centerY = 200
Dim i As Integer
For i = 20To 200 Step 20
  greenPen = New Pen(RandomColor, 20)
  radius = i
  cornerX = centerX - radius / 2
  cornerY = centerY - radius / 2
  e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(greenPen, cornerX, cornerY, radius, radius)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot this help me a lot for my exact solution